# ODBC vs. OLEDB for calling SQL Server stored procedures from Alteryx

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc, oledb, alteryx

I have the following stored procedure in SQL Server. If I run it using OLEDB in Alteryx, I get the correct result set. However, if I run it using ODBC in Alteryx, I get this error msg:

> No Columns Returned

How should I make this stored procedure work with ODBC?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      Saqib
-- Create date: 07/06/18
-- Description: Test of OLEDB vs. ODBC
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_sp] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)

    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM test_table'
    EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

Comment: Does `SQLExecute(@SQL)` work?

Comment: I don't think SQLExecute is a built-in function in the Stored Procedure in MS SQL.

Comment: I assume that means you tried, and it did not work?

Comment: @johnjps111, yes tried it. it didn't work. nor was i able to find any documentation for SQLExecute() function

Comment: SQLExecute is more of an API thing so probably (my bad) not applicable to Alteryx, which would be passing in the SQL you provide and executing it.  You;ve shown your SP definition above; could you show how you're calling it from Alteryx as well? Do you notice any difference in responses when attempting the same calls from, say, SQL Server Mgmt Studio?